# Where are the capacitors on the l298n module?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor, l298, motordriver

Note I am a beginner :)

Looking at the l298n datasheet: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf

I noticed on the block diagram and "Pin Functions" table, there are resistance and capacitor requirements. One of which is a 100nf capacitor attached between Vs and GND, and VSS and GND. [image]

However, when looking at the L298n module itself, I don't see any resistors or 100nf capacitors being used. Instead a 1nf and 2X220uf capacitors are being used.

[image]

**Are the 100nf capacitors and other resistors already "included" in the L298n IC? If not why can't I see them on the board?**

Comment: They are not in the package. They do appear to be absent. The designer could have deemed those three caps were sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not every L298N module follows the recommendations put forth in the datasheet.

I have this particular module:

[image]

(Source: https://forums.parallax.com/discussion/156410/how-to-use-a-l298n-dual-h-bridge-with-a-microcontroller-quickstart-board/p2 )

It has the bypass cap for pin 9 but not for pin 4. Fortunately pin 4 comes out as the VMS signal so it's easy to add the cap between it and GND on the bottom of the board.

Comment: I want to take another motor driver IC, (L6203) and make a module similar to this. How would I know whether to use the recommendation on the datasheet or use another design. Thanks!

Comment: Generally use the designs as presented in the datasheet. In order to save on on cost corners are cut when producing modules meant for the hobbyist market. The recommendations in the datasheet are conservative so your circuit may still work even if you omit some parts. On the other hand, if it doesn't work you'll might find yourself adding those parts back in to see if that was the problem.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: As a side question, are there any discord servers you would recommend to meet others knowledgeable about building circuits.

Comment: I'm don't use Discord but if I did I might first check out the [Electroboom discord](https://disboard.org/server/761264387683778581). You can find others using this seach link: https://disboard.org/servers/tag/electronics?sort=-member_count

Comment: Ah nice! Thanks a million 